# Expand detail row of grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

I have a problem expanding the detail row of the kendo grid. My grid is fill with 3 level data like below.

```
Parent Row
   Child Row 
     Grand Child Row
```

Each of the row have a grid. What I want to achieve is expand all detail row when clicking on a button to show those grid. Currently, I can expand all detail row but the grid for Grand Child become shrink. If manually expand it doesn't have this problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate?autoRun=true&theme=office365">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.common-office365.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.office365.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.office365.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <button id="expand" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" >Expand</button>
    <div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>

    
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
        <div class="taskGrid"></div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="Subtemplate">
        <div class="subTaskGrid"></div>
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          
            var column=[{
        "field": "",
        "title": "No.",
        "hidden": false,
        "template": "",
        "width": "40px",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": []
    },
    {
        "field": "r_tasker",
        "title": "Admin Name",
        "hidden": false,
        "template": "<span title='#:r_tasker#'>#:r_tasker#</span>",
        "width": "180px",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": []
    },
    {
        "field": "r_tasker_email",
        "title": "Email",
        "hidden": false,
        "template": "<span title='#:r_tasker_email#'>#:r_tasker_email#</span>",
        "width": "180px",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": []
    },
    {
        "field": "taskColumn",
        "title": "taskColumn",
        "hidden": true,
        "template": "<span title='#:taskColumn#'>#:taskColumn#</span>",
        "width": "",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": [{
                "field": "r_task_receive_date",
                "title": "Receive Date",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_task_receive_date#'>#:r_task_receive_date#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_task_action_date",
                "title": "Action Taken on",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_task_action_date#'>#:r_task_action_date#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_task_status",
                "title": "Action Taken",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_task_status#'>#:r_task_status#</span>",
                "width": "350px",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_ref_no",
                "title": "ID",
                "hidden": true,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_ref_no#'>#:r_ref_no#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_name",
                "title": "Applicant Name",
                "hidden": true,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_app_name#'>#:r_app_name#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_ic",
                "title": "Passport",
                "hidden": true,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_app_ic#'>#:r_app_ic#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_com_dep",
                "title": "Company / Department",
                "hidden": true,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_app_com_dep#'>#:r_app_com_dep#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_task_duration",
                "title": "Duration",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_task_duration#'>#:r_task_duration#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": "<span title=\" The duration is derived by hours from Received Date to Action Taken on.\">Duration(Hours) <i class='k-icon k-i-info'><i></span>",
                "taskColumn": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "field": "firstTaskColumn",
        "title": "firstTaskColumn",
        "hidden": true,
        "template": "<span title='#:firstTaskColumn#'>#:firstTaskColumn#</span>",
        "width": "",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": [{
                "field": "r_ref_no",
                "title": "ID",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_name",
                "title": "Applicant Name",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_ic",
                "title": "Passport",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_com_dep",
                "title": "Company / Department",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_task_duration",
                "title": "Total Duration",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": "<span title=\" The total duration is derived by the sum up of all iteration's duration.\">Total Duration(Hours) <i class='k-icon k-i-info'><i></span>",
                "taskColumn": []
            }
        ]
    }
];
          var row=[{
        "r_tasker": "A",
        "r_tasker_email": null,
        "taskColumn": "[{\"r_app_name\":\"AAAA_ CH UPDATE\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-001\",\"r_app_ic\":\"AA\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"ABAN\",\"r_task_duration\":\"1.5\",\"subitem\":[{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"03/03/2021 05:59:21\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"03/03/2021 06:48:26\",\"r_task_status\":\"Approved application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-001\",\"r_app_name\":\"AAAA_ UPDATE\",\"r_app_ic\":\"AA\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"ABAN\",\"r_task_duration\":\"1\"},{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"03/03/2021 05:43:20\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"03/03/2021 05:55:59\",\"r_task_status\":\"Require Review on application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-001\",\"r_app_name\":\"AAAA_ CH UPDATE\",\"r_app_ic\":\"AA\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"ABAN\",\"r_task_duration\":\"0.5\"}]},{\"r_app_name\":\"a\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-003\",\"r_app_ic\":\"a\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"a\",\"r_task_duration\":\"10563\",\"subitem\":[{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"23/03/2021 05:21:14\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"25/03/2021 10:40:49\",\"r_task_status\":\"approved application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-003\",\"r_app_name\":\"a\",\"r_app_ic\":\"a\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"a\",\"r_task_duration\":\"53.5\"},{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"10/01/2020 04:02:01\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"23/03/2021 01:25:01\",\"r_task_status\":\"Require  Review on application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-003\",\"r_app_name\":\"a\",\"r_app_ic\":\"a\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"a\",\"r_task_duration\":\"10509.5\"}]}]",
        "firstTaskColumn": null
    },
    {
        "r_tasker": "B",
        "r_tasker_email": null,
        "taskColumn": "[{\"r_app_name\":\"Antonio Juggler\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-004\",\"r_app_ic\":\"990809783902\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"A SDN BHD\",\"r_task_duration\":\"1\",\"subitem\":[{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"22/02/2021 12:13:03\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"22/02/2021 12:14:15\",\"r_task_status\":\"Approved application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-004\",\"r_app_name\":\"Antonio Juggler\",\"r_app_ic\":\"990809783902\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"A SDN BHD\",\"r_task_duration\":\"0.5\"},{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"22/02/2021 12:09:50\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"22/02/2021 12:11:15\",\"r_task_status\":\"Require Review on application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-004\",\"r_app_name\":\"Antonio Juggler\",\"r_app_ic\":\"990809783902\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"A SDN BHD\",\"r_task_duration\":\"0.5\"}]}]",
        "firstTaskColumn": null
    }
];
            var record=0;
             var fieldDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: row,
                pageSize: 50
            });
            var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: fieldDataSource,
                    scrollable: true,
                    detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                    detailInit: detailInit,
                    columns: column,
                        dataSource: {
                        data:row,
                    },
                    pageable: {
                        pageSize: 10000,
                        position: "bottom"
                        },
                    dataBound: function (e)
                    {
                        

                        var items = e.sender.items();
                        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                        {
                            var row = $(items[i]);
                            var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
                            // if got extra then check q_spare_3 is equal to 0 or not(folder deleted)
                            if (dataItem.taskColumn == undefined)
                            {
                                row.find(".k-hierarchy-cell").html('');
                                row.find(".k-hierarchy-col").html('');
                                $(".k-hierarchy-col").remove();
                                $(".k-hierarchy-cell").remove();
                            }
                        }
                        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));
                    }
                }).data("kendoGrid");
        });

        function detailInit(e) {
            

            var masterColumn = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns;
            var taskColumn = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < masterColumn.length; i++)
            {
                    if (masterColumn[i].field == "firstTaskColumn")
                    {
                        taskColumn = masterColumn[i].taskColumn;
                        break;
                    }
               
            }
            var detailRow = e.detailRow;
            detailRow.find(".taskGrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: jQuery.parseJSON(e.data.taskColumn),
                    pageSize: 50,
                },
                detailInit: detailInitGrandChild,
                detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#Subtemplate").html()),
                dataBound: function (e)
                {
                    var items = e.sender.items();
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                    {
                        var row = $(items[i]);
                        var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);

                        if (dataItem.subitem == undefined)
                        {
                            row.find(".taskGrid .k-hierarchy-cell").html('');
                            row.find(".taskGrid .k-hierarchy-col").html('');
                            $(".taskGrid .k-hierarchy-col").remove();
                            $(".taskGrid .k-hierarchy-cell").remove();
                        }
                    }

                },
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: taskColumn
            });
        }
        
        function detailInitGrandChild(e)
        {

            var masterColumn = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns;
            var taskColumn = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < masterColumn.length; i++)
            {
                if (masterColumn[i].field == "taskColumn")
                {
                    taskColumn = masterColumn[i].taskColumn;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var detailRow = e.detailRow;
            detailRow.find(".subTaskGrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: e.data.subitem,
                    pageSize: 50,
                },
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,                
                columns: taskColumn
            });
        }
       $('#expand').click(function (e)
        {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            $(".k-master-row").each(function (index)
            {
                grid.expandRow(this);
            });
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        .k-detail-cell .k-tabstrip .k-content {
            padding: 0.2em;
        }
        .employee-details ul
        {
            list-style:none;
            font-style:italic;
            margin: 15px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .employee-details ul li
        {
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 1.7em;
        }

        .employee-details label
        {
            display:inline-block;
            width:90px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            text-align: right;
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</div>


    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but the difference when you manually expand the grand child row is the `colspan`. Manually doing it results in a `colspan` of 5. Using the `expandRow`, outcome is 3. This is why the the grand child row does not fill the entire width. To fix, I modified the expand click event handler, like so:

```
$('#expand').click(function (e) {
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

  grid.element.find(".k-master-row").each(function() {
    var $masterRow = $(this);
    $row = $masterRow.find(".k-hierarchy-cell a.k-i-collapse");
    // only expand rows that are not expanded
    if ($row.length === 0) {
      grid.expandRow($masterRow);
      var $detailCell = $masterRow.next().find(".k-detail-cell:first");
      $detailCell.attr("colspan", "5");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is only effective on parent level, to apply it for multiple more levels, We will need to modify this function to acquire a separate Grid on each level.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate?autoRun=true&theme=office365">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.common-office365.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.office365.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.office365.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <button id="expand" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" >Expand</button>
    <div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>

    
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
        <div class="taskGrid"></div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="Subtemplate">
        <div class="subTaskGrid"></div>
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          
            var column=[{
        "field": "",
        "title": "No.",
        "hidden": false,
        "template": "",
        "width": "40px",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": []
    },
    {
        "field": "r_tasker",
        "title": "Admin Name",
        "hidden": false,
        "template": "<span title='#:r_tasker#'>#:r_tasker#</span>",
        "width": "180px",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": []
    },
    {
        "field": "r_tasker_email",
        "title": "Email",
        "hidden": false,
        "template": "<span title='#:r_tasker_email#'>#:r_tasker_email#</span>",
        "width": "180px",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": []
    },
    {
        "field": "taskColumn",
        "title": "taskColumn",
        "hidden": true,
        "template": "<span title='#:taskColumn#'>#:taskColumn#</span>",
        "width": "",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": [{
                "field": "r_task_receive_date",
                "title": "Receive Date",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_task_receive_date#'>#:r_task_receive_date#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_task_action_date",
                "title": "Action Taken on",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_task_action_date#'>#:r_task_action_date#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_task_status",
                "title": "Action Taken",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_task_status#'>#:r_task_status#</span>",
                "width": "350px",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_ref_no",
                "title": "ID",
                "hidden": true,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_ref_no#'>#:r_ref_no#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_name",
                "title": "Applicant Name",
                "hidden": true,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_app_name#'>#:r_app_name#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_ic",
                "title": "Passport",
                "hidden": true,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_app_ic#'>#:r_app_ic#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_com_dep",
                "title": "Company / Department",
                "hidden": true,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_app_com_dep#'>#:r_app_com_dep#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_task_duration",
                "title": "Duration",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": "<span title='#:r_task_duration#'>#:r_task_duration#</span>",
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": "<span title=\" The duration is derived by hours from Received Date to Action Taken on.\">Duration(Hours) <i class='k-icon k-i-info'><i></span>",
                "taskColumn": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "field": "firstTaskColumn",
        "title": "firstTaskColumn",
        "hidden": true,
        "template": "<span title='#:firstTaskColumn#'>#:firstTaskColumn#</span>",
        "width": "",
        "headerTemplate": null,
        "taskColumn": [{
                "field": "r_ref_no",
                "title": "ID",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_name",
                "title": "Applicant Name",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_ic",
                "title": "Passport",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_app_com_dep",
                "title": "Company / Department",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": null,
                "taskColumn": []
            },
            {
                "field": "r_task_duration",
                "title": "Total Duration",
                "hidden": false,
                "template": null,
                "width": "",
                "headerTemplate": "<span title=\" The total duration is derived by the sum up of all iteration's duration.\">Total Duration(Hours) <i class='k-icon k-i-info'><i></span>",
                "taskColumn": []
            }
        ]
    }
];
          var row=[{
        "r_tasker": "A",
        "r_tasker_email": null,
        "taskColumn": "[{\"r_app_name\":\"AAAA_ CH UPDATE\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-001\",\"r_app_ic\":\"AA\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"ABAN\",\"r_task_duration\":\"1.5\",\"subitem\":[{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"03/03/2021 05:59:21\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"03/03/2021 06:48:26\",\"r_task_status\":\"Approved application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-001\",\"r_app_name\":\"AAAA_ UPDATE\",\"r_app_ic\":\"AA\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"ABAN\",\"r_task_duration\":\"1\"},{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"03/03/2021 05:43:20\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"03/03/2021 05:55:59\",\"r_task_status\":\"Require Review on application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-001\",\"r_app_name\":\"AAAA_ CH UPDATE\",\"r_app_ic\":\"AA\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"ABAN\",\"r_task_duration\":\"0.5\"}]},{\"r_app_name\":\"a\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-003\",\"r_app_ic\":\"a\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"a\",\"r_task_duration\":\"10563\",\"subitem\":[{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"23/03/2021 05:21:14\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"25/03/2021 10:40:49\",\"r_task_status\":\"approved application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-003\",\"r_app_name\":\"a\",\"r_app_ic\":\"a\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"a\",\"r_task_duration\":\"53.5\"},{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"10/01/2020 04:02:01\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"23/03/2021 01:25:01\",\"r_task_status\":\"Require  Review on application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-003\",\"r_app_name\":\"a\",\"r_app_ic\":\"a\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"a\",\"r_task_duration\":\"10509.5\"}]}]",
        "firstTaskColumn": null
    },
    {
        "r_tasker": "B",
        "r_tasker_email": null,
        "taskColumn": "[{\"r_app_name\":\"Antonio Juggler\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-004\",\"r_app_ic\":\"990809783902\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"A SDN BHD\",\"r_task_duration\":\"1\",\"subitem\":[{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"22/02/2021 12:13:03\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"22/02/2021 12:14:15\",\"r_task_status\":\"Approved application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-004\",\"r_app_name\":\"Antonio Juggler\",\"r_app_ic\":\"990809783902\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"A SDN BHD\",\"r_task_duration\":\"0.5\"},{\"r_task_receive_date\":\"22/02/2021 12:09:50\",\"r_task_action_date\":\"22/02/2021 12:11:15\",\"r_task_status\":\"Require Review on application.\",\"r_ref_no\":\"O-004\",\"r_app_name\":\"Antonio Juggler\",\"r_app_ic\":\"990809783902\",\"r_app_com_dep\":\"A SDN BHD\",\"r_task_duration\":\"0.5\"}]}]",
        "firstTaskColumn": null
    }
];
            var record=0;
             var fieldDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: row,
                pageSize: 50
            });
            var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: fieldDataSource,
                    scrollable: true,
                    detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                    detailInit: detailInit,
                    columns: column,
                        dataSource: {
                        data:row,
                    },
                    pageable: {
                        pageSize: 10000,
                        position: "bottom"
                        },
                    dataBound: function (e)
                    {
                        

                        var items = e.sender.items();
                        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                        {
                            var row = $(items[i]);
                            var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);
                            // if got extra then check q_spare_3 is equal to 0 or not(folder deleted)
                            if (dataItem.taskColumn == undefined)
                            {
                                row.find(".k-hierarchy-cell").html('');
                                row.find(".k-hierarchy-col").html('');
                                $(".k-hierarchy-col").remove();
                                $(".k-hierarchy-cell").remove();
                            }
                        }
                        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));
                    }
                }).data("kendoGrid");
        });

        function detailInit(e) {
            

            var masterColumn = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns;
            var taskColumn = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < masterColumn.length; i++)
            {
                    if (masterColumn[i].field == "firstTaskColumn")
                    {
                        taskColumn = masterColumn[i].taskColumn;
                        break;
                    }
               
            }
            var detailRow = e.detailRow;
            detailRow.find(".taskGrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: jQuery.parseJSON(e.data.taskColumn),
                    pageSize: 50,
                },
                detailInit: detailInitGrandChild,
                detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#Subtemplate").html()),
                dataBound: function (e)
                {
                    var items = e.sender.items();
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                    {
                        var row = $(items[i]);
                        var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(row);

                        if (dataItem.subitem == undefined)
                        {
                            row.find(".taskGrid .k-hierarchy-cell").html('');
                            row.find(".taskGrid .k-hierarchy-col").html('');
                            $(".taskGrid .k-hierarchy-col").remove();
                            $(".taskGrid .k-hierarchy-cell").remove();
                        }
                    }

                },
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: taskColumn
            });
        }
        
        function detailInitGrandChild(e)
        {

            var masterColumn = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns;
            var taskColumn = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < masterColumn.length; i++)
            {
                if (masterColumn[i].field == "taskColumn")
                {
                    taskColumn = masterColumn[i].taskColumn;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var detailRow = e.detailRow;
            detailRow.find(".subTaskGrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: e.data.subitem,
                    pageSize: 50,
                },
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,                
                columns: taskColumn
            });
        }
        $('#expand').click(function(e){
            var masterGrid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            $("#grid").find("tr.k-master-row").each(function (index) {
                masterGrid.expandRow(this);
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                var detailRows = masterGrid.element.find(".k-detail-row");
                for (var i = 0; i < detailRows.length; i++) {
                    var detailElement = $(detailRows[i]).find(".k-grid");
                    var detailGrid = detailElement.data("kendoGrid");
                    $(detailElement).find("tr.k-master-row").each(function (index) {
                        detailGrid.expandRow(this);
                    });
                }
            }, 100); //2nd level
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        .k-detail-cell .k-tabstrip .k-content {
            padding: 0.2em;
        }
        .employee-details ul
        {
            list-style:none;
            font-style:italic;
            margin: 15px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .employee-details ul li
        {
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 1.7em;
        }

        .employee-details label
        {
            display:inline-block;
            width:90px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            text-align: right;
            font-style:normal;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</div>


    

</body>
</html>
```